# RC frequency for PWM signal

Tags: pwm, passive-filter

I have recently read [this project](https://www.instructables.com/How-to-Control-a-MOSFET-With-Arduino-PWM/) and would like to ask for some clarification regarding this statement/calculation:

*"The values shown work well an operating frequency of 1.95KHz or 13 bit operation with 8192 steps (2 to the power 13 = 8192)."*

It filters the PWM signal with R and C, but I do not understand the reasoning behind it and the calculations made.
I know the 1/2piRC cut-off frequency ... but I don't understand what it has to do with the '13 bits' he talks about.

Comment: I don't know what the 13 bit operation has to do with the cutoff frequency - nor where "13 bits" come from.  The UNO has  eight bit timers and a 16 bit timer.  I've seen libraries that do 10 bit resolution on the Arduino PWM outputs, but I've never seen 13 bit resolution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The program uses the ATMega328's "fast PWM mode 14" mode on a 16-bit counter clocked at 16 MHz (on this hardware.)

From the source of the [linked project](https://www.instructables.com/How-to-Control-a-MOSFET-With-Arduino-PWM/):

```
  TCCR1A = (1 << COM1A1) | (1 << COM1B1) | (1 << WGM11); // Fast PWM mode    
  TCCR1B = (1 << WGM12) | (1 << WGM13) | (1 << CS10);    // Fast PWM mode, no clock prescaling possible
  OCR1A = 3240;                                          // Start PWM just below MOSFET turn on
  ICR1 = 8191;                                           // Set the number of PWM steps
```

With this mode, the basic frequency of what we're counting is fixed at 16 MHz.  We count 8192 clocks which controls the period of our output.  The middle transition is controlled by OCR1A, giving a duty cycle effectively OCR1A / ICR1.  As there are 8192 possible time slots to change the phase, we have 13-bit resolution of the duty cycle.

The calculation is 16 MHz / 8192 ≈ 1.95 kHz.  The alternative mentioned is 16 MHz / 256 ≈ 62.45 kHz, where 255 is used as the ICR1 value.  There is no reason you couldn't use any value you liked, including for example 99 or 999.  You choose it according to how much precision you want of the duty cycle, and trade that off against a slower frequency.

Once you have the frequency of the output, you adjust the RC network to smooth it appropriately.

Of course the [ATMega 328 datasheet](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/aemDocuments/documents/MCU08/ProductDocuments/DataSheets/ATmega48A-PA-88A-PA-168A-PA-328-P-DS-DS40002061B.pdf) covers it (section 16.9.3), but it's terse, and you may find [this post at wolles-elektronikkiste.de](https://wolles-elektronikkiste.de/en/timer-and-pwm-part-2-16-bit-timer1) or a very similar one at [Wellys](https://wellys.com/posts/avr_c_step2/) helpful.